# Unit test for angular service didn't run

Tags: angular, unit-testing, karma-runner

I have a service that I want to test it so I create a file 'maincause.service.spec.ts' like that :

```
fdescribe('MainCauseService', () => {

let injector: TestBed;
let service: MainCauseService;
let httpMock: HttpTestingController;

beforeEach(() => {
 TestBed.configureTestingModule({
 imports: [HttpClientTestingModule],
 providers: [MainCauseService],
})
injector = getTestBed();
service = injector.get(MainCauseService);
httpMock = injector.get(HttpTestingController);
});
it('should be created', () => {
 const service: MainCauseService = TestBed.get(MainCauseService);
 expect(service).toBeTruthy();
});
 }
```

The problem is when I tap `ng test` it doesn't run anything ! Karma result : `0 specs, 0 failures`
Can anyone help me  !

Answer (score 0):

I find a solution I replace this line in the test.ts file `const context = require.context('./', true, /\.spec\.ts$/);` with `const context = require.context('./', true, /maincause.service\.spec\.ts$/);` and it works now

Comment: Assuming this is a regex that checks for files, I wouldn't hardcode the value to `maincause.service`. At the very least, you could use something like `/.+\.spec\.ts$/` to make it at least a little dynamic.